# Ember re-render a select box with model

Tags: ember.js

I have a select dropdown that is driven by another select dropdown. When Dropdown A is changed, Dropdown B is supposed to re-render itself with potentially a new set of options.

The desired behavior is that if Dropdown B has already been set to a value and Dropdown A changes, if that value in the now re-rendered Dropdown B is also available, that value would be pre-selected.

That is not happening here.

*In the template:*

```
// Dropdown A
{{ view "select" 
  content=reportTypes
  classNames="form-control"
  optionValuePath="content.type"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  value=activeTemplate }}

// Dropdown B
{{ view "select"
   content=types
   classNames="form-control"
   optionValuePath="content.value"
   optionLabelPath="content.label"
   value=model.type }}
```

*In the controller:*

```
activeTemplate: Ember.computed('model.template', Ember.ForwardCompatibility.setterGetter({
  get: function() {
    return this.get('model.template');
  },
  set: function(key, value) {
    this.set('model.template', value);
    return value;
  }
})),

types: Ember.computed('activeTemplate', function() {
  var reportType = this.get('model.reportType');

  var types = [];
  if (reportType) {
    var mapping = CloudUI.ReportUtils.typeToLocalizedKey();

    Object.keys(mapping).forEach(function(type) {
      if (reportType.hasTimeScope(type)) {
        types.push({
          label: Ember.localized.localize(mapping[type]),
          value: type
        });
      }
    });
  }

  console.log('model.type:', this.get('model.type'));

  // at the moment, types will always be ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly']
  // but we can't expect this in the future
  return types;
}),
```

**Expected behavior:** If Dropdown B's value is 'Monthly', when Dropdown A changes and one of the options in the re-rendered Dropdown B is 'Monthly', set Dropdown B to 'Monthly'.

**Actual behavior:** If Dropdown B's value is 'Monthly', when Dropdown A changes, the re-rendered Dropdown B gets set to whatever the first option is (in this case, 'Daily'). However, `this.get('model.type')` is still set to 'Monthly'.

Because `this.get('model.type')` is still properly to set to whatever Dropdown B was set to before Dropdown A was changed, why isn't the select dropdown no longer polling the model?

Using Ember v1.10.

Comment: Try `activeTemplate: Ember.computed.alias('model.template')` instead of get/set CP. By the way view is [deprecated from ember 1.13 onwards](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view).

Comment: @kumkanillam That did not work